# tensorflow add new op : could attr accept scalar tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I can't find detail info about this in [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html).

Could anyone give more detailed info?

Comment: "Attr types" section gives list of types that are valid for attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow uses attrs as "compile-time constants" that determine the behavior and type (number of inputs and outputs) of an op.
You can define an op that has a `TensorProto` as one of its attrs. For example the `tf.constant()` op takes its value as an attr, which is defined  [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7df9c6860e00b91eda0e550b11d9be52d9341d85/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc#L337) in the corresponding op registration.

There are a few limitations to this feature:

- It is not currently possible to constrain the shape of the tensor statically. You would need to validate this in the constructor for the op (where `GetAttr` is typically called).
- Similarly, it is not currently possible to constrain the element type of the tensor statically, so you will need to check this at runtime as well.
- In the Python wrapper for your op, you will need to pass the attr's value as a [`TensorProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7df9c6860e00b91eda0e550b11d9be52d9341d85/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto), e.g. by calling [`tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.util.html#make_tensor_proto) to do the conversion.

In general, you may find it much easier to use a simple `int`, `float`, `bool`, or `string` attr instead of a *scalar* `TensorProto`, but the `TensorProto` option is available if you need to encode a less common type.

Comment: I realy want that attr accept a placeholder tensor(a scalar tensor), so simple int, float,bool.. can't do this,    could TensorProto   accept placeholder tensor?

Comment: No, it can't. All attrs must have **fully-defined values** when the graph is constructed (a `TensorProto` represents the value of a tensor), and a placeholder is a symbolic tensor that can take on different values at run-time. If you need to be able to feed different values, then you must use a tensor input, and not an attr.